# Empty DBContext at startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I want to make a test database that erase its content each time the program starts in a ASP.Net/Blazor project or end.

What should I add to be sure that all the changes I made during runtime get erased when program stops ?

**Edit :** I'm also seeding data with `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext` and I want the data seeded to be kept.

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Blazor works on .NET Core. Are you using EF or EF Core? In EF Core you can use a in-memory "database" for testing

Answer (score 0):

Since Blazor only works on ASP.NET Core 3, I assume you use EF Core, not just Entity Framework.

EF Core was designed with unit testing in mind. The [Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/) chapter in the EF Core documentation explains how you to use the [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) or [SQLite provider in in-memory mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)  for testing.

Assuming your contexts have a constructor that accepts DbContextOptions, you can configure their provider from the outside, either during testing or because you want to use different connection strings.

Given this DbContext

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
    { }

    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
    ...
}
```

Using one provider or another is as simple as creating the options and calling the constructor.

**In-Memory provider**

The in-memory provider is essentially a dictionary, so it can't cover complex query scenarios. It's easier to setup and use though.

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
    .Options;

// Run the test against one instance of the context
using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
{
    var service = new BlogService(context);
    service.Add("https://example.com");
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**SQLite in-memory provider**

Using the SQLite provider is almost the same. An in-memory database is created and then the code is essentially the same as before. When the connection closes, the database and the data in it are gone.

```
using(var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

    // Create the schema in the database
    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    // Run the test against one instance of the context
    using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
    {
        var service = new BlogService(context);
        service.Add("https://example.com");
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this solution is the most correct one. So as I'm not unit testing and it seems pointelss to scope everything for now, I could just specify in `Startup.cs` the options and it will always run in memory ?

Comment: Integration test then? In that case it's better to use the SQLite provider. In both cases the data is in-memory. Only SQLite will enforce referential integrity, defaults and concurrency.